# How to register IVsEditorFactoryNotify in VS.NET extension package?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to monitor the item added event.

I have created a custom editor factory such as

```
public class ProjectEditorFactory : IVsEditorFactoryNotify, IVsEditorFactory
{
    public int NotifyDependentItemSaved(IVsHierarchy pHier, uint itemidParent, string pszMkDocumentParent, uint itemidDpendent, string pszMkDocumentDependent)
    {
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

    public int NotifyItemAdded(uint grfEFN, IVsHierarchy pHier, uint itemid, string pszMkDocument)
    {
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

    public int NotifyItemRenamed(IVsHierarchy pHier, uint itemid, string pszMkDocumentOld, string pszMkDocumentNew)
    {
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

............
}
```

And then in my Initialize method of the package

I do

```
RegisterEditorFactory( new ProjectEditorFactory());
```

but after I run, the event handler is not hit after I add a new item to the project.

Does anyone know how to catch the event?

What I actually really want is to grammatically add a few files, and then create the Dependency to one specific file. Does anyone know another way other than listening to the ItemAdded event?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want an Editor factory here, that's when you want to provide a custom editor (like the text editor inside Visual Studio). You should look into integrating with the project system. I don't remember the ways to do it via the newer project system, but you can probably get away with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchyevents(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sorry, I am too dumb for this. So are you saying if I want my VS.NET extension (Package) to be notified when an item (file) is added, my Package should implement the IVsHierarchyEvents interface? I just tried it, the event is still not hit.

Comment: No you need to grab the IVsHierarchy, and then call the AdviseHierarchyEvents method on it and pass an implementation of IVsHierarchyEvents. Take a look at http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/pga/how-do-i-get-a-project-from-a-ivshierarchy-and-viceversa/ this shows you how to grab a hold of a project. Once you have that, call http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchy.advisehierarchyevents(v=vs.80).aspx to receive events of interest.